# Qt - Can Several QtableWidgets share linked Items

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

**Qt Several tableWidgets share linked Items**

Hi, in Qt I have a QMainWindow -> centralWidget (QWidget) -> QtabWidget -> then 10 Tabs (QWidgets) -> each with up to 26 QtableWidgets:

[Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/levBD.png)

[Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3k8S.png)

The idea is that instead of this:

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Add_Player_clicked()
{
     ui->tableWidget_Players->insertRow(ui->tableWidget_Players->rowCount());
     ui->tableWidget_Defensive->insertRow(ui->tableWidget_Defensive->rowCount());
     .
     . [10 tableWidgets in Total]
     .
     ui->tableWidgetAll->insertRow(ui->tableWidget_Players->rowCount());
}
```

Is there a way so that I can add a column each time to every tableWidget with less code.

Of course that's not there is to it, in fact I want to know is there is a way to link some of the Items of each that are actually the same Item but it's repeated in each like for example the **Player Name** is the same per row in each tableWidget, so if the user edits the name in one, it should change it in the same row in every tableWidget.

Is there a way to link them somehow, or the only way it's checking for item changes as signals.

I would also like that if I sort by column in one tableWidget, the new arrangement of the rows should be the same in every tableWidget.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction, the only idea I have it's using signals for ItemChanged. Isn't there a better way?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are *the same data*, you should consider getting some nice *model view controller* action going (also say that phrase a lot when applying for jobs, they like that ;))

To do this you need to create a [tablemodel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-tablemodel-example.html). And a `TableView` widget. This way, the data is shared, so it exists in only one place. All your `TableView`s just show the data. You can have a look at [QSortedFilterProxy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) to filter your data for a specific view(i have never used this, so don't know). That way you have your `playerModel` somewhere, and each view has a proxyModel that only shows for instance the active players.